# Function cannot find failed memory allocation

Tags: c, memory, multidimensional-array, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Function `int load(const char *filename, int ***ptr, enum save_format_t format)` should load data from binary or **text file** (which name is saved under `filename` pointer) to matrix which is under `ptr` pointer to matrix. File extension depends on value of variable format: 0 or 1 (in function I showed there is only option with format=0, which is primarily for text files, because only this one makes trouble). Proper data in file looks for example as below:

**10 20 30 40 50 60 70 -1**

**100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 -1**

For data exact like an example above, data should be loaded like this:

```
int A[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, -1};

int B[] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, -1};

int D[] = {A, B, C, NULL};
```

That means that every row has to end with '-1', (data has to be loaded to matrix with '-1'). Pointer to row after the last row should be equal to NULL.

**If in any part off function allocation failed, function should return 4.**

Tests carried out on file with extension ".bin" and with heap limit return this error:

> Function should return 4, but it returned 0.

I use notation like for example `**ptr` because I'm not allowed to use square brackets.

Can someone help me how can I make my function return the right integer. My function is as it follows:

```
int load(const char *filename, int ***ptr, enum save_format_t format) {
    if (filename == NULL || ptr == NULL || format != 0 && format != 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int val = 0;
    int **temp = NULL;
    FILE *fp, *pp;
    if (format == 0) {
        int i = 0, x = 0, h = 0, w = 0;
        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            return 2;
        }
        pp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (pp == NULL) {
            fclose(fp);
            return 2;
        }
        int val2 = 0;
        while (1) {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &val2) != 1) {
                if (i == 0 || val != -1) {
                    fclose(fp);
                    fclose(pp);
                    return 3;
                }
                break;
            }
            val = val2;
            if (val == -1) {
                h++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (i == h) {
            fclose(fp);
            fclose(pp);
            return 3;
        }
        i = 0;
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        temp = malloc(sizeof(temp) * (h + 1));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            fclose(fp);
            fclose(pp);
            return 4;
        }
        *(temp + h) = NULL;
        for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            val = 0, w = 0;
            while (val != -1) {
                if (fscanf(pp, "%d", &val) == EOF) {
                    break;
                }
                w++;
            }
            if (*(temp + i) != NULL) {
                *(temp + i) = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * w);
                if (*(temp + i) == NULL) {
                    for (int s = 0; s < i; s++) {
                        free(*(temp + s));
                    }
                    free(temp);
                    fclose(pp);
                    fclose(fp);
                    return 4;
                }
            } else {
                fclose(fp);
                fclose(pp);
                free(temp);
                return 0;
            }
            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                fscanf(fp, "%d", *(temp + i) + x);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(pp);
    }
    *ptr = temp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's going on in the code? What is the point of `temp`? `h`? `s`? Maybe use more descriptive variable names? Maybe add some comments? Why no `realloc`? Why are you opening the same file twice? And for cumbersome error handling, you might want to just refactor it to multiple functions or use the goto error management. When `if (*(temp + i) != NULL) {` is true, you return `0` and I think `*ptr` is unset.

Comment: This line `if (*(temp + i) != NULL) {` is for sure wrong. The memory pointed to by `temp + i` is uninitialized so it makes no sense to read it and test if it's NULL.

Comment: `int D[] = {A, B, C, NULL};` Where did that come from? The example file has nothing like that

Comment: I'll try to fix my mistakes and describe everything properly quickly

Comment: `temp = malloc(sizeof(temp) * (h + 1));` is incorrect: it should be `temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp) * (h + 1));`

Comment: Should `int D[] = {A, B, C, NULL};` be `int C[] = {A, B, NULL};` instead?

Comment: Regarding; `if (*(temp + i) != NULL) {
                *(temp + i) = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * w);`  This says, if the `temp+i` entry in `temp` is already in use, then overlay that entry.  Are you sure you want to be doing that?  The result is a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading a string and parsing with `strtol`.
The memory allocations will return NULL when there is no RAM available.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

int load ( char const *filename, int ***ptr) {
    if ( filename == NULL || ptr == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    char entry[100] = "";
    char *end = NULL;
    int **temp = NULL;
    int *temprow = NULL;
    long int val = 0;
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    int problem = 0;
    int result = 0;
    FILE* fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen ( filename, "r");
    if ( fp == NULL) {
        perror ( filename);
        return 2;
    }

    while ( 1 == ( result = fscanf ( fp, "%99s", entry))) {
        if ( -1 == val || ( 0 == rows && 0 == cols)) {
            if ( -1 == val) {
                ++rows;
            }
            if ( NULL == ( temp = realloc ( *ptr, sizeof **ptr * ( rows + 2)))) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem realloc *ptr\n");
                problem = 4;
                break;
            }
            *ptr = temp;
            *( ( *ptr) + rows) = NULL;
            *( ( *ptr) + rows + 1) = NULL;//sentinel

            cols = 0;
        }
        errno = 0;
        val = strtol ( entry, &end, 10);
        if ( entry == end) {//nothing could be parsed to int
            problem = 3;
            break;
        }
        else if ( 0 != *end) {//extra characters after int
            problem = 3;
            break;
        }
        if ( ( errno == ERANGE && ( val == LONG_MAX || val == LONG_MIN))
        || ( errno != 0 && val == 0)) {// parsing error from strtol
            perror ( "input error");
            problem = 3;
            break;
        }
        if ( val > INT_MAX || val < INT_MIN) {
            problem = 3;
            break;
        }
        if ( NULL == ( temprow = realloc ( *( ( *ptr) + rows), sizeof ***ptr * ( cols + 2)))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem realloc *( (*ptr) + row)\n");
            problem = 4;
            break;
        }
        *( ( *ptr) + rows) = temprow;
        ++cols;
        *( *( ( *ptr) + rows)) = cols;//save cols in index 0
        *( *( ( *ptr) + rows) + cols) = val;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if ( 0 == result) {
        problem = 3;
    }
    return problem;
}

int main ( void) {
    char const *filename = "ints.txt";
    int **array = NULL;
    int row = 0;
    int each = 0;

    load ( filename, &array);

    row = 0;
    while ( array && ( *(array + row))) {
        each = 0;
        while ( each <= *( *(array + row))) {
            printf ( "%d\n", *( *(array + row) + each));
            ++each;
        }
        ++row;
    }

    row = 0;
    while ( array && ( *(array + row))) {
        free ( *(array + row));
        ++row;
    }
    free ( array);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `if (i == h)` seems incorrect: what if the file contains a single row with a `-1` terminator, in other words an empty matrix?
- `temp = malloc(sizeof(temp) * (h + 1));` should be `temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp) * (h + 1));`
- `if (*(temp + i) != NULL) {` read an uninitialized entry in the array allocated by `malloc()`. The test should be removed and you should always allocate the row.

Here is a modified version:

```c
int load(const char *filename, int ***ptr, enum save_format_t format) {
    if (filename == NULL || ptr == NULL || format != 0 && format != 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int **temp = NULL;
    FILE *fp, *pp;
    if (format == 0) {
        int i = 0, x = 0, h = 0, w = 0, val = 0;
        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            return 2;
        }
        pp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (pp == NULL) {
            fclose(fp);
            return 2;
        }
        // determine the number of rows
        val = 0;
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &val) == 1) {
            if (val == -1)
                h++;
        }
        if (val != -1) {
            // empty file or file does not end with -1
            fclose(fp);
            fclose(pp);
            return 3;
        }
        temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp) * (h + 1));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            fclose(fp);
            fclose(pp);
            return 4;
        }
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            w = 0;
            while (fscanf(pp, "%d", &val) == 1) {
                w++;
                if (val == -1)
                    break;
            }
            if (w == 0 || (*(temp + i) = malloc(sizeof(int) * w)) == NULL) {
                while (i-- > 0) {
                    free(*(temp + i));
                }
                free(temp);
                fclose(pp);
                fclose(fp);
                return 4;
            }
            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                fscanf(fp, "%d", *(temp + i) + x);
            }
        }
        *(temp + h) = NULL;
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(pp);
    }
    *ptr = temp;
    return 0;
}
```